# Finding integer solutions to $x^2-yx+ay+b = 0$

Tags: diophantine-equations

What's the best technique to find integer solutions for $x$ & $y$ to equations in the form $x^2-yx+ay+b = 0$ where $\space(a,b)\space$ are known integers (or even just to find the number of solutions that exist)?

Comment: Add your attempts to your question thanks

Comment: $x^2-yx+ay+b = 0 \implies (y - 2 a)^2 - (2 x - y)^2 = 4 (a^2 + b)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x-a$. The equation becomes

$$uy=(u+a)^2+b=u(u+2a)+a^2+b$$

If $a^2+b\not=0$, we must have $u\mid a^2+b$, in which case there are only finitely many solutions. If $a^2+b=0$, the equation to solve is $uy=u(u+2a)$, with infinitely many solutions of the form $(u,y)=(0,y)$ and $(u,y)=(u,u+2a)$.

Comment: $u y=(u−a)^2+b$ is not correct

Comment: @Lozenges, oh gosh, you're right! Thanks, I'll fix it.

Comment: The equation factors as follows: $a^2+b=(y-x-a)(x-a)$. Please refer to the comment above by @Dmitry Ezhov

Comment: @Lozenges, arghh, another math error. I thought making a change of variable made it easier to see what's going on, but I see it also made it all too easy for me to make stupid mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

Give $\quad x^2-yx+ay+b = 0\quad$ we know we can get integer $(y)$ solutions for any integer $x\ne a$.

$$y =\frac {-b + x^2}{a - x} \land a \ne x$$

If we then solve for $x$, we can use any of the resulting $y$-values to get an $x$

$$x = \frac{y - \sqrt{y (y - 4 a) - 4 b}}{2}$$

but this is a round-robin thing. We have seen above that there are infinitely many solutions:
$$a,b,y\in\mathbb{Z}\quad\land\quad x\in\mathbb{Z}-\{a\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Equation given by "OP" is equal to:

$x^2+b=y(x-a)$  ---(1)

Equation $(1)$ has solution:

$x=3(2k-1)$

$y=(11k^2-10k+2)$

$a=6(k-1)$

$b=-3(k-1)^2$

For, $k=2$, we get:

$(a,b)=(6,-3)$  and

$(x,y)=(9,26)$